# Отслеживание изменений в SQLite WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

Допустим имеется две базы данных в SQLite. Каким образом изменения в одной, со временем, можно применить в другой?
Или по другому, как можно синхронизировать записи из одной базы данных в другую. Т.е. сравнить две базы данных, при найденных добавленных строках объединить их в одну таблицу.

Comment: Это называется репликация. Сходу гуглится, например, эта статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/200360/

Comment: Читал данную статью, но хотелось бы небольшой пример на wpf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129532

Comment: В данный момент у меня так и реализовано, но что будет, если с одного ПК один backup зальют, с другого другой и получится, что один перезапишет другой, а хотелось бы, чтобы одна БД, обновляла другую. Если конечно я правильно понимаю код по ссылке.